# MS SQL Server 2000 IPv6

Tags: ipv6, sql-server

Does anyone know if SQL Server 2000 supports IPv6?  I did some googling around, but I'm not finding any documentation on it.

Comment: I very much doubt it. MS, IIRC, first released experimental support for IPv6 well after 2000. I doubt it would be retro-fitted to such a critical product until it was a mainstream part of the OS (ie. Windows Server 2008).

Comment: I haven't found much for any discussing it out there, but I imagine you're probably right.  I'm sure I'll find out soon enough when we start converting over to IPv6, and SQL 2000 will probably just have to stay dual-stacked.

Answer (score 1):

No.

IPv6 support is only available from [SQL Server 2005 and later](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/hh994905.aspx).

Comment: ... and SQL 2005 included a major redesign of connectivity, so that's not just Microsoft not listing it as supported, they actually added the functionality then.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [here](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/IPv6-Support-Microsoft-Windows.html) you can find some useful informations.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it looks like that's just for Windows Server instead of SQL Server.

Comment: The IPv6 support stars form Windows Server version and then the appplication.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.